# Adding a header to a 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Tried this but does not work as intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[2][2] = {10,11,12,13};
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("ds%d",i+1);
        printf("\n");

        for(j = 0; j<2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result that appeared:

```
ds1
10      11      ds2
12      13
```

The needed result should be the following:

```
ds1  ds2
10   11
12   13
```

Comment: Print the header in a separate loop first. Then print the data in the double-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print the header first separately.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[2][2] = {10,11,12,13};
    int i,j;

    /* This loop prints the headers */
    for(i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("ds%d\t",i+1);
    }
    printf("\n");   /* new line to start printing data */

    /* This loop prints the data */
    for(i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n"); /* new line after each row of data */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know why if there are more than 20 columns printed in cmd when running the program, the data appear messy? It seems that the cmd cannot support that many columns. Even after zooming out it still shows them in a strange way.

Comment: Because the command window does "line-wrapping", if the line is too wide, it wraps it to the next line.

Comment: @user17850871 Pipe the output into a file and load that in a decent text editor. Then you will see that the formatting is fine.